# Display content in dependency of special roles

Tags: users

We use Drupal 7.26 on Windows which Apache.
We use the book module for our software documentations, which can have special variants eg a user manual, a configuration manual, a user manual written for use with a special program. To realise this we use the module "Restricted Text" and "Content access" to give users the possiblity to see the content in dependency of their roles. The roles are for "user" manual, "configuration" manual or maybe in variant for "AutoCAD".

With restricted Text module you can make content visible/invisible with special input filter in dependency to the roles eg [restrict:roles=RT_CONFIG]Content which is only visible if you have the role RT_Config [/restrict].

Now I'm searching for a possibility to filter the content for the user, independent from the user roles. An example: A user should be able to view one manual in 2 variants, for this he has these roles:

- RT_Config (to see the content which belongs to the configuration manual)
- RT_ACD (to see the content which belongs to special variant AutoCAD)
- RT_INV (to see the content which belongs to special variant Inventor)

My suggestion is, that the user make a choice to see the configuration manual in variant AutoCAD, but the content depending to Inventor should be invisible - for this the user maybe musst temporary loose the role RT_INV. Is this possible?

Thank you for any idea to this complex thing.
Matroschker

Comment: Currently we think to have a solution. We use the flag module to assign or delete roles at runtime if the user check or uncheck link/check box.

Comment: Yes, such things are possible to solve with the Flag and the Rules module. We decide to use the flags to identify which content should be displayed - but we didn't use the actions from the Flag module.
We checked the flags with the rules module and add or remove the roles and with it the content was displayed or not.

Matroschker